# How to expose minikube ingress to internet

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

I have install a minikube on my linux-laptop (Computer A)

[image]

and deploy some service on it :

```
$ minikube service list
```

| NAMESPACE | NAME | TARGET PORT | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cert-manager | cert-manager | No node port |  |
| cert-manager | cert-manager-webhook | No node port |  |
| default | aws | 5000 | http://192.168.49.2:30728 |
| default | azure | 5000 | http://192.168.49.2:31794 |
| default | gcloud | 5000 | http://192.168.49.2:32367 |
| default | hft | 5000 | http://192.168.49.2:30970 |
| default | hftf | 5000 | http://192.168.49.2:30612 |
| default | kubernetes | No node port |  |
| default | open | 5000 | http://192.168.49.2:31547 |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller | http/80 | http://192.168.49.2:31053 |
|  |  | https/443 | http://192.168.49.2:30302 |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller-admission | No node port |  |
| kube-system | kube-dns | No node port |  |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper | No node port |  |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard | No node port |  |

As you can see there is 6 service create with fastAPI and that are behind an ingress.
I have set my ingress with the host `galigator.fun`. Cert-manager is ready to fire, but for now TLS is comment in the ingress.
`galigator.fun` is DNS name I own.

```
$ minikube addons enable ingress
$ kubectl describe ingress
Name:             multiplex-applications
Namespace:        default
Address:          192.168.49.2
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 ()
Rules:
  Host           Path  Backends
  ----           ----  --------
  galigator.fun  
                 /v1/aws/(.+)            aws:5000 (172.17.0.11:5000)
                 /v1/azure/(.+)          azure:5000 (172.17.0.14:5000)
                 /v1/gcloud/(.+)         gcloud:5000 (172.17.0.13:5000)
                 /v1/deepml/best/(.+)    hftf:5000 (172.17.0.10:5000)
                 /v1/deepml/edge/(.+)    hft:5000 (172.17.0.3:5000)
                 /v1/deepml/razor/(.+)   open:5000 (172.17.0.8:5000)
Annotations:     cert-manager.io/issue-temporary-certificate: true
                 cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-staging
                 kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    52m (x3 over 53m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

The error from Default backend seem not related to my problem...

If add an entry to `/etc/hosts` with `minikube ip` and `galigator.fun` then I can run my services without problem.
But there are not available from Computer B not Computer C.

**How to access my services from Computer B and Computer C ?**

*I don't want to change any configuration in computer B & C.*

As I understand, the `minikube ip` isn't know from my Internet Box; it is not a physical equipement.
My minikube run from my kubuntu-21.04 and is start with `minikube start --ports=80,443` or just `minikube start` but I can't observe a difference.

Another thing that don't look to work.

```
$ kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 deployment/ingress-nginx-controller 80:80 --namespace ingress-nginx
Unable to listen on port 80: Listeners failed to create with the following errors: [unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: permission denied]
error: unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{80 80}]
```

I have properly test the connectivity between Internet and Computer A for port 80 & 443 using an Apache. Since I have remove that server.

Answer (score 1):

First as the doc explain I try to play with `minikube` startup options.

```
minikube start --listen-address='0.0.0.0' --ports=80,443
```

But as we can see it doesn't change anything:

```
$ docker container ls |grep minikube
0aafb00fd97d   gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.25   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 weeks ago    Up 22 minutes   127.0.0.1:49172->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49171->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49170->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49169->8443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49168->32443/tcp   minikube
```

So if we investigate deeper on error of command :

```
kubectl port-forward -n ingress-nginx  --address 0.0.0.0 service/ingress-nginx-controller 80:80 443:443
```

we can find that binding to port `80` and `443` but they are below `1000` and require extra privilege/root. And `kubectl` isn't a root process, for goods reasons.

So an ugly solution that work could be to do something like that :

```
kubectl port-forward -n ingress-nginx  --address 0.0.0.0 service/ingress-nginx-controller 50000:80 50001:443
```

And then change the NAT rules in the InternetBox. But I don't like it because `minikube` is an implementation detail that should not impact another hardware.

So a less horrible solution is to give kubectl the write to bind to low number ports...

```
$ man 7 capabilities | grep -A 1 CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
       CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
              Bind a socket to Internet domain privileged ports (port numbers less than 1024).
```

So command should be :

```
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/bin/kubectl
```

and then

```
kubectl port-forward -n ingress-nginx  --address 0.0.0.0 service/ingress-nginx-controller 80:80 443:443
```

it works to...

**But there is one major concern here, we have to redo the last command on every startup, and the last two ones on every upgrade...**

If someone have a good answer, that could also work for a background server on a `LAN`, I would love it.

Port `80` is require only during the execution of the challenge from cert-manager. So a solution that could get close it, could also be interesting.